# Xamarin Forms iOS entry rendered narrow in height

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

The Entry elements throughout my whole Xamarin.Forms application seem to be either cropped in height, or seem to have lost their padding, resulting in a very narrow (in height) entry (loosing almost 30% of its height).

This happened after I updated my existing Xamarin.Forms (Android/iOS) application to support larger screens (iPhone 7+), by updating the iOS launchscreens *

* Could have been caused by something else, since I've only been able to run on these larger devices after the launchscreen-update. However, no nuget-updates or other styling has been changed in the process.

- The issue exists for any entry, even as basic as `<Entry />`
- Other form elements (labels, dropdowns etc) do not experience this issue.
- Before the update to support 7plus > screens, this issue was non-existing.
- The issue cannot be reproduced in a new, blank Xamarin.Forms application, using the same Xamarin.Forms nuget package (2.5.0.121934). Thus, entry's are rendered normally.
- Furthermore, there is no additional styling applied to the entry, nor to the application on a global level.

[Example of an entry rendered in a new project, and once incorrect in my current project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEaF9.jpg)

Any tips on what could be the cause are well appreciated.

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: Hi @SrustiThakkar, it happens even on a plain ContentPage with only <Entry /> in it. The issue is limited to this specific app though (Xamarin.Forms PCL created +/- 2yrs ago), i can't reproduce it in a new blank app. I've added a screenshot with the current app, and one of the exact same xaml copied into a new blank app.

Comment: You might try updating xamarin.forms via nuGet in all packages
Then delete /bin and /obj folders in your iOS project and do a clean and rebuild